# challenges and how to implement SQL SERVER 2012 from physical to cloud server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, cloud, azure-sql-database

I am interested in knowing the challenges and steps for sql database migration from physical server to cloud server. Is there changes i need to make in database , any login change , any security change etc. ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are migrating from an older version of SQL Server to a newer version on Azure VM, please consider [breaking changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/breaking-changes-to-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2017), [discontinued features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/discontinued-database-engine-functionality-in-sql-server-2016) and [deprecated features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2017).

A comparison of migration methods and recommendations can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-migrate-sql).

Do not store databases on Drive D which is a temporary storage. You should place TempDB on a folder on D drive, but everything there disappears when the VM is rebooted. To deal with that, please read [this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2014/09/25/using-ssds-in-azure-vms-to-store-sql-server-tempdb-and-buffer-pool-extensions/) article.

Standard Storage has varying latencies and bandwidth and is only recommended for dev/test workloads. Production workloads and I/O intensive workloads should use Premium Storage.

Selecting the appropriate VM size is crucial for performance. Select DS2 or DS3 or higher.  All IO is throttled based on instance size.

Comment: Thanks Alberto, i am not thinking to upgrade or change sql server version which is 2012 now. Let me know steps on same and pre checks and post migration  implementation if any .

Comment: In addition to the resources provided by Alberto, you can have a look at this documentation page for an overview of the various options you have when moving from SQL Server on premise to SQL Server on virtual machine. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-migrate-sql

Comment: Consider Guest OS configurations: Enable read caching on the disk(s) hosting the data files and TempDB; Enable instant file initialization for data files; Format disks with 64-KB allocation unit size; Stripe multiple Azure data disks to get increased IO throughput..  Post installation tasks: configure backups to Azure storage; Enable database page compression; Move all databases to data disks, including system databases; Move SQL Server error log and trace file directories to data disks; Enable locked pages; Apply Windows and SQL Server updates;